# Celery Periodic Task with Broadcast Queue

Tags: rabbitmq, celery-task, celerybeat

i use celery and celery beat with rabbit mq and everythings works fine.

but now, i've created an periodic task on a broadcast queue and this is not working.

celeryconfig.py

```
from kombu.common import Broadcast

CELERY_QUEUES=(
  Broadcast('for_all_webhosts')
)
```

task.py

```
class PeriodicScript(PeriodicTask):
  run_every = crontab(minute='*/2', hour='*')
  time_limit = 300
  soft_time_limit = 600

  queue = 'for_all_webhosts'

  def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
    logger.error("START")
```

In the Log file i can see that the task is triggerd, but the task is not running

```
Scheduler: Sending due task tasks.periodic_xxx.PeriodicScript (tasks.periodic_xxx.PeriodicScript)
```

How it is possible to start a periodic script in a broadcast queue ?

Thanks

Marcel